# Dynamically changing columns in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have an API data source I am refreshing daily to gather power bi activity. Each day, the data returns a different amount of columns, so it might have 60 one day and 80 (+20) additional another day.

When I try to refresh the dataset in the Power BI Service, it naturally fails and states that the new columns cannot be found in the row set.

I have explored many options such as creating a combine table, however I do not know all the names of the columns that could come in each day so this failed because it was very static. Does anyone know of a way to dynamically handle these daily changes?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

The only way to refresh a data source that has changing schema is to [unpivot](https://products.support.services.microsoft.com/en-us/office/unpivot-columns-power-query-0f7bad4b-9ea1-49c1-9d95-f588221c7098) that table and bring it into your model as key/value pairs.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to do.

If you're just trying to change all extra columns from `type any` to `type number`, you can try something like

```
let
  Source = #"table with extra columns",
  OtherColumnNames = List.RemoveItems(
    Table.ColumnNames(Source),
    #"List of known column names"
  ),
  #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(
    Source,
    List.Transform(
      OtherColumnNames,
      each {_, type number}
    )
  )
in
  #"Changed Type"
```

or, if that's something you will be doing to multiple tables you could turn it into a function, like a query with a name of "fTransformOtherColumnTypes" with the following code.

```
(
  #"List of known column names" as list,
  #"table with extra columns" as table,
  Type as type
) =>
let
  Source = #"table with extra columns",
  OtherColumnNames = List.RemoveItems(
    Table.ColumnNames(Source),
    #"List of known column names"
  ),
  #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(
    Source,
    List.Transform(
      OtherColumnNames,
      each {_, Type}
    )
  )
in
  #"Changed Type"
```

and then your other queries can use it, e.g. `fTransformOtherColumnTypes({"name","color","org", "alias"}, #"your source data", type number)`